# How can i read CSS rule from local file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i want to do is to read what's inside a css file ( local file ) 
but

- i cant use GET because i don't use a server and i don't want to
- i don't want to allow chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
- and i have an error that can't get the fille with protocol file://

my goal is to save an html file but before that to get the css from link stylesheet and add it to the html file between

```
css=' <style>\n'
    //+ get the css
    + '</style>\n';
```

Comment: You want to do this in a web page served by a http server? why? (you may need to write a web extension, though, not sure if that would work either)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs You don't need server. Browser is capable to display static files on it's own. There is no server-side scripting involved.

Comment: Why you need to include style instead of using external source? Also when working with `file://` there is quite strict CORS rules. You can access only same-dir or below, not above, so basically `../../js` will not work

Comment: i want something like
- cssRules() / rules()
- insertRule()
- deleteRule()

Comment: @Justinas fi i include style with file:// and i send the file to someone the css will not work

Comment: any browser has the *save file to ...* what's wrong with that ?

Comment: @noureddineamrane Use relative path.

Answer (score 0):

The solution  to your problem is:

```
<style>
@import url("style.css");
</style>
```

Classic way to link stylesheets.

JQuery way:

```
<!doctype html >
<html>
    <head>
       <noscript>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
       </noscript>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div></div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.when($.get("test.css"))
            .done(function(response) {
                $('<style />').text(response).appendTo($('head'));
                $('div').html(response);
            });
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but fi i import the style and i send the file to someone, it will not work

Comment: "I know this is not using Javascript" so you decided to answer anyway?

Comment: @noureddineamrane  `@import` or via js, is the same , it will not work. you need to save the file with the css inside it before sending the whole thing elsewhere. You should clarify your question ;)

Comment: I tried my best to answer the question... Maybe better luck next time...

Answer (score 0):

Use must have all paths as relative ones instead of absolute. And your structure should be like this:

```
root
 | - index.html
 | - css
 | -- styles.css
 | -- images
 | --- background.png
 | --- button.jpg
 | - js
 | -- main.js
```

Then you use relative paths in index.html:

```
<html>
    <link href="/css/styles.css"></style>
    <script src="/js/main.css">
```

---

CORS rules applies strictly in browser when on `file://` protocol: all resources that are being requested must be on same level as current file or below (deeper in dir tree).

So if you have file in `root/pages/index.html` it can't request `../css/styles.css` because of CORS.